# Count Unique on two fields with a Join

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count, group-by

I have:
Table A with Movie Name, Movie ID
Table B with Movie ID, Barcode (one movie may have multiple barcodes)
Table C with customers' Rentals which has Barcode, Customer ID.

I am trying to count total customer rentals for each movie. I want to count "unique" Movie Names (not barcodes) for all customers. If two customers rent the same movie, it should be counted as twice. If the same customer rents the same movie twice (regardless of the barcode), it should be counted as once.

My code right now looks like:

```
SELECT movie.NAME,
    count(UNIQUE movie_rental.barcode)
FROM movie_barcode
INNER JOIN Movie_Rentals
    ON movie_barcode.barcode = Movie_rentals.barcode
INNER JOIN movie
    ON movie_barcode.movie_number = movie.movie_number
GROUP BY movie.NAME;
```

I am using Oracle.

Kindly advise.

Comment: use `DISTINCT` not `Unique`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT movie.NAME, COUNT(DISTINCT movie_rental.barcode)
FROM movie_barcode
INNER JOIN Movie_Rentals ON movie_barcode.barcode = Movie_rentals.barcode
INNER JOIN movie ON movie_barcode.movie_number = movie.movie_number
GROUP BY movie.NAME;
```